# Entityframeworkcore erroring - not able to add migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Even finding a million question here on stachexchange none seem to fix my issue.

I have an api application in .net6.0 Which I want to add a database

The first thing apparently is that there is no startup file anymore.

my appsettings:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ApplicationDbContext": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=NetworkMonitor;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  }
```

my entry in program class

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContext")));
```

dbcontext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            :base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<HostInformation> HostInformation { get; set; }

    }
```

when using this applicationdbcontext class i gert an error of 'unable to create an object of type applicationdbcontext'

When I add an empty constructor which I had found in some questions and answers:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {

    }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        :base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<HostInformation> HostInformation { get; set; }

}
```

I get 'no database provider has been configured for this context'
Which seems obvious as there is an empty constructor.

Any other ideas what I am missing here?

as for packages I have entityframeworkcore
.sql
and
.tools installed

Comment: I’ve never seen .\\SQLEXPRESS in a connection string. Are you sure you didn’t mean localhost or (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDb?

Comment: I meant localhost yes,

Comment: i'm using sql express not localdb tough, but currently I have added docker which means my server is myip\sqlexpress, however I use 2 slashes for the unescaped slashes or whatever that is called otherwise visual studio is complaining

Comment: oke this is weird, when using the same connectionstring and classes in my main webapplication rather than my api, everything works which is weirdn coz I had set the right startup project.

Answer (score 1):

Are you reading your appsettings properly?

Maybe you are missing

```
builder.Configuration
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
.AddEnvironmentVariables()
.Build();
```

in your Program.cs file.

Before you add the DBContext with "builder.Services.AddDBContext" write the piece of code from above.
If you use this check if any nuget packages are missing as well.

For ".SetBasePath()" you need  - "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions"
and for ".AddJsonFile" you need " Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json"

If this not work check the file settings of your "appsettings.json". Maybe your not copying your appsettings.json in your directory.

Comment: Try to bold to emphasize your words. Instead of leaving it with “ “ characters.

Comment: appsettings wasn't the problem, but thanks